# XSLT - select consecutive elements with the same attribute but ignore later same element/same attribute

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```
  <doc>
    <paragraph>AAA</paragraph>
    <paragraph stylename="numbered" num="1">BBB</paragraph>
    <paragraph stylename="numbered" num="2">CCC</paragraph>
    <paragraph>DDD</paragraph>
    <paragraph>EEE</paragraph>
    <paragraph stylename="numbered" num="1">FFF</paragraph>
    <paragraph stylename="numbered" num="2">GGG</paragraph>
    <paragraph stylename="numbered" num="3">HHHh</paragraph>
    <paragraph>III</paragraph>
  </doc>
```

I need to count the total number of **consecutive** paragraph[@stylename='numbered'] and output:

```
<paragraph>AAA</paragraph>
<paragraph count="1" totalnums="2">BBBa</paragraph>
<paragraph count="2" totalnums="2">CCC</paragraph>
<paragraph>DDD</paragraph>
<paragraph>EEE</paragraph>
<paragraph count="1" totalnums="3">FFF</paragraph>
<paragraph count="2" totalnums="3">GGG</paragraph>
<paragraph count="3" totalnums="3">HHH</paragraph>
<paragraph>III</paragraph>
```

I can't figure out how to output the @count or the total number (@totalnums) of consecutive @stylename="numbered".

Currently, I get the total number of  paragraph/@stylename="numbered" in the whole file.

Any pointers and/or code would be greatly appreciated. (XSLT-1.0 solution preferred, although 2.0 might be possible to implement)

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `@totalnums` of the 2nd group be 3 instead of 2?

Comment: Oops. Yes, the second block of paragraphs should have totalnums="3"!  Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:for-each-group` with `group-adjacent`. To achieve the same in XSLT 1.0 is more difficult:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="k1" match="paragraph[@stylename='numbered']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::paragraph[not(@stylename='numbered')][1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph[@stylename='numbered']">
    <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('k1', generate-id(preceding-sibling::paragraph[not(@stylename='numbered')][1]))" />
    <!-- if this is the first one in the group -->
    <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($grp[1])">
        <xsl:for-each select="$grp">
            <paragraph count="{position()}" totalnums="{last()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </paragraph>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example input, this will return:

**Result**

```
<doc>
  <paragraph>AAA</paragraph>
  <paragraph count="1" totalnums="2">BBB</paragraph>
  <paragraph count="2" totalnums="2">CCC</paragraph>
  <paragraph>DDD</paragraph>
  <paragraph>EEE</paragraph>
  <paragraph count="1" totalnums="3">FFF</paragraph>
  <paragraph count="2" totalnums="3">GGG</paragraph>
  <paragraph count="3" totalnums="3">HHHh</paragraph>
  <paragraph>III</paragraph>
</doc>
```

This is different from the result shown in your question, but I believe it is correct.

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k.  I had to modify the code slightly as the real-life example was more complicated but there's no way I would have achieved a result without your help. Much appreciated!